# How do I link a cell in excel (Sheet1) to another cell that contains text from drop down box (Sheet2)

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have created a drop down box in a sheet in G1. In G2 I want to create a hyperlink that when clicked would go to another sheet's cell that contains what is in the drop down box.

Is that possible?

[Sheet 1 Data Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX130.png)

[Sheet 2 Drop Down and Hyperlink Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiJNY.png)

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps you mean something similar to `=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(MATCH(G1;Sheet2!B1:B20;0);2;1;1;"Sheet2");"Jump to '"&G1&"'")`?

Comment: I don't think that's the answer s that would still keep me in Sheet 2? I have uploaded photos of what I mean. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Did you change **G1** to **B1** and **G2** to **C1**? Okay, so be it.  For the data shown in your screenshots, the following formula should work: `=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A1:F10=B1)*ROW(Sheet1!A1:F10));SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A1:F10=B1)*COLUMN(Sheet1!A1:F10));1;1;"Sheet1");"Jump to '"&B1&"'")`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I get the "Are you trying to type a formula box come up)

Comment: It's annoying that this resource does not allow you to post files with sample data and solutions. Check out [**my Dropbox file**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cg25rhf1f7grvra/jumpToCell.xlsx?dl=0) - does it work? (BTW, it seems to me that I know the reason why your Excel doubted the formula: my sheets are called Sheet1 and Sheet2, and yours are "Sheet 1" and "Sheet 2". Space in the name)

Comment: That is the answer John you legend. Thanks so much.